# Subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, gap, computer-algebra-systems, computational-algebra

Is there some program or a location which would allow me to work and calculate with the subgroups of the group $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: Try the free software [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap0.html).

Answer (score 7):

[GAP](https://www.gap-system.org) is open source. You can download and install it as explained [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Releases/index.html). Then, for example, you can do the following.

Create the group in question:

```
gap> G := GL(2, Integers mod 8);
GL(2,Z/8Z)
gap> Size(G);
1536
```

Calculate conjugacy classes of its subgroups (long output, takes a minute or two):

```
gap> ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G);
[ Group([],[ [ ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ) ] ])^G, 
  Group([ [ [ ZmodnZObj( 3, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 3, 8 ) ] ] ])^G, 
  Group([ [ [ ZmodnZObj( 5, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 5, 8 ) ] ] ])^G, 
...
  Group([ [ [ ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 7, 8 ) ] ], 
      [ [ ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 4, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ) ] ], 
      [ [ ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 2, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 7, 8 ) ] ], 
      [ [ ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 4, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ) ] ], 
      [ [ ZmodnZObj( 3, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 3, 8 ) ] ], 
      [ [ ZmodnZObj( 5, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 3, 8 ) ] ], 
      [ [ ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 2, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ) ] ], 
      [ [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 7, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 7, 8 ) ] ], 
      [ [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 1, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 5, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ] ] ])^G, GL(2,Z/8Z)^G ]
gap> time;
88590
```

The `time;` command returns the CPU time in milliseconds spent by GAP to perform the last command.

To demonstrate several other features of GAP, you can assign this list to a variable called `cc`. In this assignment I use double semicolon `;;` instead of a single one to suppress the output. Also, the second call to `ConjugacyClassesSubgroups` for the *same* group `G` returns the result at no cost, since it retrieves the data stored in `G` after the previous call:

```
gap> cc:=ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G);;
gap> time; 
1
```

Now, let's take some class, e.g. `cc[12]`:

```
gap> c:=cc[12];
Group([ [ [ ZmodnZObj( 3, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ) ], [ ZmodnZObj( 0, 8 ), ZmodnZObj( 7, 8 ) ] ] ])^G
```

It contains 6 conjugate subgroups:

```
gap> Size(c);
6
```

And their list can be obtained as follows:

```
gap> AsList(c);
[ <group of 2x2 matrices of size 2 over (Integers mod 8)>, <group of 2x2 matrices of size 2 over (Integers mod 8)>, 
  <group of 2x2 matrices of size 2 over (Integers mod 8)>, <group of 2x2 matrices of size 2 over (Integers mod 8)>, 
  <group of 2x2 matrices of size 2 over (Integers mod 8)>, <group of 2x2 matrices of size 2 over (Integers mod 8)> ]
```

Hope this gives an idea what you can do with GAP. Further questions that may be useful are:

- [List Conjugacy Classes in GAP?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604094/)
- [How to find all subgroups of a group in GAP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569349/)
- [How do I get the subgroups of my group? (GAP F.A.Q.)](https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7)
- [Which resources are available to self-study GAP?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104195/)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from GAP, the other software system that specializes in group theoretical calculations is Magma. Unlike GAP, Magma is not open source, but there is a calculator that is available for use online [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).  A disadvantage of this is that you have to type in all of your commands in advance and then run them all. Here is an example:

Input:

```
G := GL(2, Integers(8));
S := Subgroups(G);   //representatives of conjugacy classes of subgroups
#S;
AS := AllSubgroups(G);
#AS;
```

Output:

```
2265
24587
```

which are the numbers of conjugacy classes of subgroups, and all subgroups, respectively.